# Interfacing 20x4 character LCD with LPC54628

Tags: i2c, lcd, interface, lpc, hd44780

This is the very first time I am dealing with the task of hardware interfacing.
I needed to interface a 20x4 character LCD with an LPC54628 microcontroller.

I am using https://www.sunrom.com/p/20x4-lcd-black-on-yellowgreen which has a built-in HD44780 LCD controller and to connect it with LPC54628 microcontroller I have used I2C LCD Backpack - PCF8574 (https://www.sunrom.com/p/i2c-lcd-backpack-pcf8574) which interface the LCD using the I2C interface.

As I mentioned before the very first time I am dealing with this type of work, so anyone suggests where to start? it will be good if the example is available.

I have gone through the below links but unable to get how to use it in our case.

https://e2e.ti.com/support/archive/launchyourdesign/m/msp430microcontrollerprojects/666684 https://github.com/xreef/PCF8574_library

Note: Here we haven't used the internal LCD controller of LPC microcontroller, as we needed to keep LPC free from it to perform other tasks and even we don't have a high data flow rate on LCD.

Answer (score 0):

It's already interfaced electrically if you connect the module to the I2C port.

So seems like you want some kind of software, in which case  you can either read the HD44780 and PCF8574 datasheets and write your own, or use a search engine to see if someone has [done it already](https://github.com/mathertel/LiquidCrystal_PCF8574).

If you're using some oddball language or whatever, you can try porting some source code that is available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have gone through the above link and the same type LCD interfaced with Aurdino.